# SKAction not running on SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

The `SKAction` on my `SKShapeNode` isn't working, the code isn't getting executed, and the node isn't moving, even though the console is logging "Snake is moving". Is is because the node is a property of the SKScene and the actions are part of lower scope functions?

```
class LevelScene: SKScene, SnakeShower {

    var snake: Snake {
        let theSnake = Snake(inWorld: self.size)
        return theSnake
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.backgroundColor = .green
        snake.delegate = self
    }

    var myNode: SKShapeNode {
        let node = SKShapeNode(rectOf: snake.componentSize)
        node.position = snake.head
        node.fillColor = .red
        return node
    }

    func presentSnake() { // function called by the snake in the delegate (self)
        self.addChild(myNode)
        startMoving()
    }

    func startMoving() {
        print("snake is moving")
        myNode.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.move(by: self.snake.direction.getVector(), duration: 0.2),
            SKAction.run({
                if self.myNode.position.y > (self.size.height / 2 - self.snake.componentSize.height / 2) {
                    self.myNode.removeAllActions()
                }
            })
        ])))
    }
}
```

It used to work when they property was declared in the same function as the action

Comment: what do you mean by 'isn't working' - what exactly happens?

Comment: @SteveIves Edited.

Comment: Change `self.snake.direction.getVector()` to `CGVector(dx:200, dy:200)` (for example) to see if `getVector()` is the problem.

Comment: Nothing happened. And I tried `getVector()` in a playground, and it works as intended.

Comment: OK, so simplify the action so that it just does the `move` and not the `removeAllActions()`.

Comment: I would say (from a brief look ) that he is working on a wrong node. He first create a node and add it, then gets another node and try to run an action on it, but the node is not in a node tree.

Comment: There is only 1 node (myNode) in all the code

Comment: @Whirlwind. I think you're right. `myNode` is a computed property. `self.addChild(myNode)` adds a node, but there is no `myNode` property. Then `myNode.run` computes a new node but doesn't add it to the scene before trying to run the action on it. but it's a different node anyway.

Comment: @Fayyouz Actually, you don't have a single node called myNode. You have a computed property myNode that every time it is referenced, returns a new, distinct SKShapeNode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`myNode` is a computed property. `self.addChild(myNode)` adds a node, but there is no `myNode` stored property.

`myNode.run` First computes a new node without adding it to the scene. Then it calls the run the action on it. but since it's a different node that is not on the scene, it will never run.

Change your `myNode` defintion to:

```
var myNode : SKShapeNode!
```

and in `didMove(to view:` add:

```
myNode = SKShapeNode(rectOf: snake.componentSize)
myNode.position = snake.head
myNode.fillColor = .red
```

Comment: 6 up votes!? Seriously? I can't imagine many people have a problem caused by using a computed property for their node.

Answer (score 5):

I had an issue almost identical to this, where I had unresponsive child nodes in a referenced node. Turns out that referenced nodes default to isPaused being true (answer thread found [here](https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/loading-a-skscene-but-actions-are-not-working/48608))

The solution was to change the isPaused property to false.

```
referencedNode.isPaused = false
```

Comment: This might not have been OP's problem, but it was mine. Reference nodes are great... except when they are not.